# Apache libcloud, dns, and godaddy - Name or service not known

Tags: python, libcloud

Using that apache libloud docs and valid credentials i get the below error trying to list domains on godaddy. Does libcloud noi longer support godaddy?

```
>>> from libcloud.dns.types import Provider
>>> from libcloud.dns.providers import get_driver
>>> cls = get_driver(Provider.GODADDY)
>>> driver = cls('twst', 'adfadf', 'dsdfsdf')
>>> zones = driver.list_zones()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/dns/drivers/godaddy.py", line 146, in list_zones
    '/v1/domains/').object
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 782, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 979, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/httplib_ssl.py", line 266, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>>
```

Comment: ps I am using version 0.20.1

Comment: Can you run `ping api.godaddy.com` from the same machine on which you are running this python script?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was a bug in the driver. The "host" attribute on the connection class was incorrectly set to a URL instead of a hostname.

I pushed a fix for that - https://github.com/apache/libcloud/commit/a3ba6a4751623224f16175df9175ec06b29cdc1a

You can test this change by installing latest in development version from git using pip - `pip install git+https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/libcloud.git@trunk#egg=apache-libcloud`

I have confirmed the change is working locally, but if you encounter any more issues, please let us know.

```python
from libcloud.dns.types import Provider
from libcloud.dns.providers import get_driver
cls = get_driver(Provider.GODADDY)
driver = cls('twst', 'adfadf', 'dsdfsdf')
print driver.list_zones()
...
libcloud.dns.drivers.godaddy.GoDaddyDNSException: <GoDaddyDNSException in MALFORMED_API_KEY: Malformed API key>
```

In addition to that, I will also go ahead and push a change so a more friendly exception is thrown in case the "host" attribute is set to a value which is not a hostname.